# Regex to remove bracket but not its contents

Tags: regex, scripting

I would like to remove constant text and brackets from a String using regex. e.g.

```
    INPUT                  Expected OUTPUT
   var x = CONST_STR(ABC)  var x = ABC
   var y = CONST_STR(DEF)  var y = DEF
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Since you question is vague here is an approach remove the first and last char in the string ! use substring method !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with regex:

```
(?<==\s)\w+\(([^)]+)\)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tI2fP6/1)
which means:

- `(?<==\s)` - lookbehind for `=` and space (`\s`), the regax need to fallow these signs,
- `\w+` - one or more word characters (A-Za-z_0-9) this might be upgraded to naming rules of language from code you are processing,
- `\(` - opening bracket,
- `([^)]+)` - capturing group (`\1` or `$1`) for one or more characters, not closing brackets,
- `\)` - closing bracket,

Just remember that in Java you need to use double escape character `\`, 
like in:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("var y = CONST_STR(DEF)".replaceAll("(?<==\\s)\\w+\\(([^)]+)\\)", "$1"));
    }
}
```

with output:

> var y = DEF

The `$1` in `replaceAll()` is a call to captured groups nr 1, so a text captured by this fragment of regex: `([^)]+)` - words in brackets.

Comment: I am not sure, but i guess the `==>` should point to the output instead of beeing part of the string

Comment: @KevinEsche the `==> ABC` is irrelevant for matching, you can remove it without any change, the result is stil: `ABC`

Comment: ==> was just to symbolize output. I will update the question.

Comment: For my case I changed it (?<==\s)CONST_STR\(([^)]+)\)